# IntelliJ - maven project, View/Tool Windows without maven option

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.1. I have generated a maven project structure from the command line using a custom archetype. I open that project in IntelliJ this way: `File/New/Project from Existing Sources/Create project from existing source`. A project is opened but I don't see a maven option in View/Tool Windows. I would like to run mvn install from IDE. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **Maven support** for the project that you have created.

Simply right-click on the project --> Add Framework Support --> Choose `maven` from the option.

For detail, you can follow the steps mentioned here [Add maven support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html).